# Windows chkdsk claims my disks are fine, application errors suggest otherwise

Tags: windows, postgresql, file-corruption

I'm running a postgres 14 database on a windows 11 machine.

Postgres has started generating some errors including the following...

> ERROR: XX002: index "tableA_i1" contains corrupted page at block 1807

and

> ERROR: XX001: invalid page in block 38 of relation pg_tblspc/16402/PG_14_202107181/16404/125828

Googling these errors doesn't produce a lot of solutions, but many suggest underlying disc corruption may be the cause. If I run chkdsk (actually I run it via explorer, select 'c', right click, properties, tools, click on 'check') then it tells me the disk is fine.

What's my best approach for resolving this? Maybe the disk *is* corrupted (it's an SSD), but `chkdsk` is missing it? or maybe postgres is mistaken? I'm running a stable version of postgres, there are no other indicates of disc corruption, but the postgres errors keep popping up, and they're always *new* errors in different tables/indexes. Each time I drop/recreate the objects I think it's cured, then half a day later I get a similar error in a different object.

Update - SMART data for the disc lists all statuses as 'good' a full overnight run of `chkdsk` gives no indication of any errors except for this bit.....

> Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.
>
> Windows has made corrections to the file system. No further action is
> required.

But a bit further down in the log it says

> ```
>      0 KB in bad sectors.
> ```

So I think the disc is good, over to dba.stackexchange I think.

Comment: The manufacturer of the SSD probably has a utility which will get the S.M.A.R.T. data from the drive, which could show something like a counter for "media errors". Have a look and see if the utility says there is any problem with the S.M.A.R.T. data.

Comment: Also check if Postgres can verify the integrity of the DB.

Comment: @John Although it's an old answer, apparently not: [Database consistency checker in postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55762/database-consistency-checker-in-postgresql).

Comment: `chkdsk` by default checks the filesystem structures, not the actual file data. If a surface scan comes back okay then it is possible that the file data, as written by the program, is corrupt. Databases do not like system or program crashes happening while they are writing.

Comment: As other said, chkdsk verifies the file system, not file content. It may be worthwhile to post actual screenshot of SMART report. Bitmap is a file in which each bit represents a cluster's state: used/unused. I don't know how usual errors in Bitmap are, I never have them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SMART attributes of the disk using a product such as
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)
or CrystalDiskInfo.
Include a screenshot of the attributes in your post if you would like us
to have a look.

If the SMART attributes look good (Speccy will tell you that),
then you have a corrupted database which does not mean a bad sector.
You will need to return the database from backup.

If the SMART attributes show errors, then the disk may have some issues.
This does not necessarily mean that is unusable, that is if no new
bad sectors are discovered.

Run `chkdsk /f /r` to verify all sectors, then have a second look at the
SMART data. In this mode, `chkdsk` will be slow to finish.
Ensure you have backups before starting, as this operation can be
destructive if the disk is in pre-fail state.

Comment: Speccy has been installed - all SMART attributes are good. Trying to run chkdsk /f /r, but this requires a lock on the drive and needs a re-boot

Comment: This is very good news. Let's wait now for the chkdsk results.